# QLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I cannot store the company that my client belongs to. The company is a foreign key and when I click register customer I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'Tim' for column `customerlist`.`customers`.`company` at row 1 (SQL:  insert into `customers` (`company`, `name`, `document`, `phone`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Tim, Felix Botta, 04919407939, +55.41984081085,felix.botta@gmail.com, 2021-02-14 20:55:15, 2021-02-14 20:55:15))

CustomerController

```
class CustomersController extends Controller
{
public function index(){
    $customers = Customer::get();
    return view('customers.list', ['customers' => $customers]);
}

public function new(){
    $companies = Company::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('customers.form', ['companies' => $companies]);
}

public function add( Request $request ){

    $customers = new Customer;
    $customers = $customers->create( $request->all() );
    
    return Redirect::to('/customers');
}

public function edit( $id ){
    $customers = Customer::findOrFail( $id );
    return view('customers.form', ['customers' => $customers]);
}

public function update( $id, Request $request ){
    $customers = Customer::findOrFail( $id );
    $customers->update( $request->all() );
    return Redirect::to('/customers');
}

public function delete( $id ){
    $customers = Customer::findOrFail( $id );
    $customers->delete();
    return Redirect::to('/customers');
}}
```

form.blade

> 

```
                   <form action="{{ url('customers/add') }}" method="post">
                       @csrf
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="">Empresa:</label>
                        <select name="company" class="form-control">

                        @foreach($companies as $company)

                        <option value="{{ $company->name }}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
                        
                        @endforeach
                        </select>
                        
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">CPF /  CNPJ:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="document" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Telefone:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-mail:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
                    </form>
                    @endif
             
            </div>
```

> 

```
class CreateCustomersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 256);
        $table->string('document', 256);
        $table->string('phone', 128);
        $table->string('email', 128);
        $table->foreignId('company')->constrained('companies');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('customers');
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the migration the `company` column is integer and foreign key that points to companies table and according to error you are passing string value `Tim` for `company` column. So in blade view change

```
<option value="{{ $company->name }}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
```

to

```
<option value="{{ $company->id }}">{{ $company->name }}</option>
```

Comment: Friend, now I am a message when trying to edit the form: ErrorException
Undefined variable: companies (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\customerlist\resources\views\customers\form.blade.php)

Comment: @Botta I believe thats a separate question as this one is related to inserting a new record. Can you please ask a new question with all the relevant detail like your blade look like and how you are passing data to your view that would be good

Comment: @Botta From the initial thought i guess you need to add  ` $companies =Company::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();` in your edit method of controller and pass companies to your view